# Create firebase account on behalf of users

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to find a way to allow users to create and setup firebase project on their own google account from a client app, and get all their project information, urls and so on.

I took a look at the new project management api but can not figure out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The management API currently does not support the creation of a new Google Cloud project.  You are free to [file a feature request](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) for that, but it's worth pointing out that project creation is a complex issue and needs to be gated by abuse prevention measures.

You might also want to look into [Google Cloud APIs](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/create) for dealing with projects.